# How to replace null values in XML

Tags: java, xml

I am adding some more tags in xml file by using DOM parser. I am creating some new tags using DOM parser and want to set their values by passing arraylist. My arraylist contains values which I am retrieving from database.

My code is a follows:

```
loading file using dom parser


  for(String s:a.List){
 Element n= doc.createElement("value");
n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(s)));

    }
```

here I am creating new tag and passing values of s in that tag.

```
Output I am getting:

<value>1</value>

<value>2</value>

<value>3</value>

<value>null</value>

<value>null</value>

<value>4</value>
```

;
;
so on

```
Expected output:

<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>

<value>3</value>

<value/>

<value/>

<value>4<value>
```

I want to remove null which is coming from databse to arraylist and than to xml and get form as mentioned above
Please help...

Comment: Can you post the code inside your for loop?

Comment: I have editing my code...please have a look

Comment: I think if you don't add a text node it will automatically collapse. I've posted an answer that checks if the String is null before appending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Empty Tags:

The `String.valueOf()` is forcing `null` to be converted to the String `"null"`. Just remove that conversion and the null tags will collapse:

```
for(String s : a.List){
    Element n = doc.createElement("value");
    n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s)); // null renders as empty
}
```

The same collapsing should happen for empty Strings `""` (which might be convenient if you're doing something else with the String too):

```
for(String s : a.List){
    Element n = doc.createElement("value");
    if(s == null) { s = ""; } // force nulls to be empty Strings
    n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s));
}
```

...or you can conditionally omit the child (which also creates a collapsed tag):

```
for(String s : a.List){
    Element n = doc.createElement("value");
    if(s != null) {
        n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s)); // only append non-null values
    }
}
```

## No Tags:

If you wanted to omit the tag entirely you could do this:

```
for(String s : a.List){
    if(s != null) {
        Element n = doc.createElement("value");
        n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems it will remove full tags of null..I don't want to remove tag..I want like this <value/>

Comment: will surely try this

Comment: @user8548920 - Having read a bit more, I think you want to add the node, but with an empty value, i.e. `""`. I've updated my first code block accordingly.

Comment: @user8548920 - Actually this answer suggests `null`, `""`, or not adding the child are all equivalent... and I've just spotted your error. Remove the `String.valueOf()`. You're forcing the null to be Stringify'd!

Comment: can u please repost your previous code too along with these two

Comment: @user8548920 - Updated with all 3 variants (that I believe work).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
String value = String.valueOf(s);
if (! 'null'.equals(value)) { n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value)); }
```

This should leave the node `n` empty if `s` is `"null"`.

Comment: tried similar stuff..something like this but not exactly this..was getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

I have try below code:

```
for(String b:a)
{
    Element valuesElements = doc.createElement("values");
    if(b!=null)
    {
        valuesElements.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(b));
    }
        rootElement.appendChild(valuesElements);
}
```

and get below result:

```
<root><values>a</values><values/></root>
```

Probably this is what you want